# Using form method POST to an existing PHP array

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

Using the following form to POST to the same page upon clicking submit:

```
<form action="" method="post"><a class="buttonnohover">
Enter URL: </a><input type="text" name="term2" class="buttonnohover"/>
<input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Add URL" />
</form>
```

Top of the code then needs to call the form POST and append to existing array of URLs (`$myUrls`) upon refresh. At the moment it just replaces the existing array value.

```
    <?php 

    try 
    {
        //URLs Array
        $myUrls = array($_POST['term2']);

        //Array Push for $myUrls
        array_push($myUrls,$term2);

...
```

Not sure what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this,

```
  <?php

    if(isset($_POST['term2'])){

          @session_start();

          $myUrl = array($_POST['term2']);

          // DEFINE A SESSION ARRAY [CHECK BEFORE EXISTED OR NOT}]
          $_SESSION['myUrls'] =count($_SESSION['myUrls'])>0?$_SESSION['myUrls']:array();

          //ADDED TO SESSION ARRAY
          array_push($_SESSION['myUrls'],$myUrl);

          //GET ARRAY FROM SESSION
          $myUrls = $_SESSION['myUrls'];

          //PRINT THE RESULTS
          print_r($myUrls);

   }



  ?>

  <form action="" method="post"><a class="buttonnohover">
  Enter URL: </a><input type="text" name="term2" class="buttonnohover"/>
  <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Add URL" />
  </form>
```

Comment: Thanks heaps man. This was not quite what I wanted but put me on the right track!

Answer (score 1):

> At the moment it just replaces the existing array value.

Because you are directly assigning it to `$myUrls` variable like this `$myUrls = array($_POST['term2']);`

Do like this...

```
$term2 = array($_POST['term2']); // assign it to the $term2 variable instead of $myUrls
array_push($myUrls,$term2);
```

(or)

```
array_push($myUrls,array($_POST['term2']));
```

Comment: This just makes the $term2 var into the already posted variable from the form? Essentially it creates another array?!?

Comment: You could make use of the second way i suggested as it pushes `$_POST['term2']` directly to your `$myUrls` array

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to add the value for `term2` to your array of URLs you can just append it to the end:

```
$myUrls = array(); // This will normally be populated with your values
$myUrls[] = $_POST['term2'];
```

Comment: Don't do this `$myUrls = array();` because OP already has some values on `$myUrls` array, doing this will overwrite the existing values.

Comment: I wasn't telling them to make a new array. That was just to demonstrate in my code that it was an array so the next line would make sense. That's why I added the comment to hopefully make that clear.

Comment: This does nothing. term2 adds to existing array entry, but upon adding another value, the new added term2 value replaces the newly added array value.